# Fetching email using PHP imap messes up inline embedded images

Tags: php, email, imap, webmail

I made a **`webmail`** php class to fetch my domain's webmail.
Everything runs perfectly except that when the email has embedded images (like signatures), the images are fetched with **CID** in their **src** and also are treated as attachments.

```
<img src="cid:auto_cid_2093934881" />
```

So i end up with a broken source image (in its original place in the email body) and an attachment of the same image that actually works. But i don't need the image to be an attachment, i just want the images to be shown in their places.

Can anyone help me fix this class so it can fetch the images correctly?

**Here's my code to get a single email:**

```
<?php
    $uid=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email_id']);
    ini_set("max_execution_time",360);

    /* connect to server */
    $hostname = '{***.com:143/notls}INBOX';
    $username = 'fadi@***.com';
    $password = '*******';

    /* try to connect */
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to domain:' . imap_last_error());

    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$uid,0);
    $header = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $uid);
    $fromaddr = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;

    $webmail = new Webmail();
    $message = $webmail->getEmailBody($uid,$inbox);

    $attachments = $webmail->extract_attachments($inbox,$uid);
    $attach_hrefs = '';
    if(count($attachments)!=0){

        $target_dir = "emails/".$uid;
        if (!is_dir($target_dir)) {
          // dir doesn't exist, make it
          mkdir($target_dir);
        }

        foreach($attachments as $at){

            if($at[is_attachment]==1){

                file_put_contents($target_dir.'/'.$at[filename], $at[attachment]);
                $attach_hrefs .='<a target="new" href="'.$target_dir.'/'.$at[filename].'">'.$at[filename].'</a> ';

            }
        }

    }
?>
```

**Here's the webmail class:**

```
<?php
class Webmail{

function getEmailBody($uid, $imap)
{
    $body = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/HTML");
    // if HTML body is empty, try getting text body
    if ($body == "") {
        $body = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/PLAIN");
    }
    return $body;
}

function get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $structure = false, $partNumber = false)
{
    if (!$structure) {
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);
    }
    if ($structure) {
        if ($mimetype == $this->get_mime_type($structure)) {
            if (!$partNumber) {
                $partNumber = 1;
            }
            $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_UID);
            switch ($structure->encoding) {
                case 3:
                    return imap_base64($text);
                case 4:
                    return imap_qprint($text);
                default:
                    return $text;
            }
        }

        // multipart
        if ($structure->type == 1) {
            foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $subStruct) {
                $prefix = "";
                if ($partNumber) {
                    $prefix = $partNumber . ".";
                }
                $data = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $subStruct, $prefix . ($index + 1));
                if ($data) {
                    return $data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function get_mime_type($structure)
{
    $primaryMimetype = ["TEXT", "MULTIPART", "MESSAGE", "APPLICATION", "AUDIO", "IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER"];

    if ($structure->subtype) {
        return $primaryMimetype[(int)$structure->type] . "/" . $structure->subtype;
    }
    return "TEXT/PLAIN";
}
function extract_attachments($connection, $message_number) {

    $attachments = array();
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($connection, $message_number);

    if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

        for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

            $attachments[$i] = array(
                'is_attachment' => false,
                'filename' => '',
                'name' => '',
                'attachment' => ''
            );

            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $message_number, $i+1);
                if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
                elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    return $attachments;

  }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try bellow class for fetch mail body with inline image**
**Note** See **`get_mail_body($body_type = 'html')`** method in class to that store mail body inline image to local server you need to **change it as you directory layout.**

I hope this help you.

```
    $email_message = new Email_message();
    $mailbody = $email_message->get_mail_body();
```

;

```
class Email_message {

    public $connection;
    public $messageNumber;    
    public $bodyHTML = '';
    public $bodyPlain = '';
    public $attachments;
    public $getAttachments = true;

    public function __construct($config_data = array()) {

        $this->connection = $config_data['connection'];
        $this->messageNumber = isset($config_data['message_no'])?$config_data['message_no']:1;
    }

    public function fetch() {

        $structure = @imap_fetchstructure($this->connection, $this->messageNumber);
        if(!$structure) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if(isset($structure->parts)){
                $this->recurse($structure->parts);
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    public function recurse($messageParts, $prefix = '', $index = 1, $fullPrefix = true) {

        foreach($messageParts as $part) {

            $partNumber = $prefix . $index;

            if($part->type == 0) {
                if($part->subtype == 'PLAIN') {
                    $this->bodyPlain .= $this->getPart($partNumber, $part->encoding);
                }
                else {
                    $this->bodyHTML .= $this->getPart($partNumber, $part->encoding);
                }
            }
            elseif($part->type == 2) {
                $msg = new Email_message(array('connection' =>$this->connection,'message_no'=>$this->messageNumber));
                $msg->getAttachments = $this->getAttachments;
                if(isset($part->parts)){
                    $msg->recurse($part->parts, $partNumber.'.', 0, false);
                }
                $this->attachments[] = array(
                    'type' => $part->type,
                    'subtype' => $part->subtype,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'data' => $msg,
                    'inline' => false,
                );
            }
            elseif(isset($part->parts)) {
                if($fullPrefix) {
                    $this->recurse($part->parts, $prefix.$index.'.');
                } else {
                    $this->recurse($part->parts, $prefix);
                }
            }
            elseif($part->type > 2) {
                if(isset($part->id)) {
                    $id = str_replace(array('<', '>'), '', $part->id);
                    $this->attachments[$id] = array(
                        'type' => $part->type,
                        'subtype' => $part->subtype,
                        'filename' => $this->getFilenameFromPart($part),
                        'data' => $this->getAttachments ? $this->getPart($partNumber, $part->encoding) : '',
                        'inline' => true,
                    );
                } else {
                    $this->attachments[] = array(
                        'type' => $part->type,
                        'subtype' => $part->subtype,
                        'filename' => $this->getFilenameFromPart($part),
                        'data' => $this->getAttachments ? $this->getPart($partNumber, $part->encoding) : '',
                        'inline' => false,
                    );
                }
            }

            $index++;

        }

    }

    function getPart($partNumber, $encoding) {

        $data = imap_fetchbody($this->connection, $this->messageNumber, $partNumber);
        switch($encoding) {
            case 0: return $data; // 7BIT
            case 1: return $data; // 8BIT
            case 2: return $data; // BINARY
            case 3: return base64_decode($data); // BASE64
            case 4: return quoted_printable_decode($data); // QUOTED_PRINTABLE
            case 5: return $data; // OTHER
        }


    }

    function getFilenameFromPart($part) {

        $filename = '';

        if($part->ifdparameters) {
            foreach($part->dparameters as $object) {
                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                    $filename = $object->value;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!$filename && $part->ifparameters) {
            foreach($part->parameters as $object) {
                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                    $filename = $object->value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $filename;

    }

    function get_mail_body($body_type = 'html')
    {
        $mail_body = '';
        if($body_type == 'html'){
            $this->fetch();
            preg_match_all('/src="cid:(.*)"/Uims', $this->bodyHTML, $matches);
            if(count($matches)) {
                $search = array();
                $replace = array();
                foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
                    $unique_filename = time().".".strtolower($this->attachments[$match]['subtype']);
                    file_put_contents("./uploads/$unique_filename", $this->attachments[$match]['data']);
                    $search[] = "src=\"cid:$match\"";
                    $replace[] = "src='".base_url()."/uploads/$unique_filename'";
                }
                $this->bodyHTML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->bodyHTML);
                $mail_body = $this->bodyHTML;
            }
        }else{
                $mail_body = $this->bodyPlain;
        }
        return $mail_body;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. help a lot. just for beginner, start point is  : $email_message = new Email_message(['connection' => $mailbox, 'message_no' => $id]);